# How do I get an item from a list by just knowing its position in a list

Tags: python

How to select an item from a list just by knowing what its position is inside the list.
If the list is
`[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]`
is there a function that operates something like this
`theoreticalfunction(list,position in list)` and then the output is the item that was in the selected position

Comment: literally one of the most basic things you learn, use `some_list[index]`, remember that indexes start from 0 tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index of an element on the list you can use listName[index] to get it's value.
 For example
 `lst = [a,b,c,d,e] 
 print(lst[0]) # returns a`